# agileUploader onReady

Tags: jquery, flash

I am using the agileUploader to resize images before uploading to a server but I am having trouble determining when the uploader is ready.

Does anyone know if there is a way to display a simple 'loading' message until the browse button is ready?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.holdReady()` to Delay the ready event until a custom plugin has loaded.

eg:

```
$.holdReady(true);
$.getScript("myplugin.js", function() {
     $.holdReady(false);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/